# Geforce 740M installing cuda

Tags: 16.04, drivers, graphics, cuda

I am trying to install cuda on Ubuntu 16.04 so what I first did was to check the pre-installation actions and verify that my system does fulfill the dependencies.

I deleted everything related to nvidia, downloaded the .deb file and installed it.

After that I added following to the PATH variable:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.1/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
```

now I tried this command:

```
cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version
```

but in the proc/driver/ directory is no nvidia folder...

and If it try to `make` a sample I get errors because there are no libraries or whatever even everything has been installed.

I am trying it for 3 days now :/

Comment: It may be easier for you to install the nvidia-cuda-toolkit package from the default Ubuntu 16.04 repositories instead, which installs the nvidia-384 driver along with it as a dependency. However nvidia-cuda-toolkit in 16.04 is version 7.5, which is not the latest version 9.1.

Comment: I mean the installation was not a problem. And the 9.1 toolkit also contains the nvidia-384 driver so I don't think it would make a difference, do you?

Comment: `cat /proc/driver/nvidia/version` returns the expected results on my Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: you did install v 7.5?

Comment: When I installed 7.5 to use CUDA in Blender and rebooted, it booted to a black screen. I reverted to the previous Nvidia driver and uninstalled 7.5 because my Ubuntu 16.04 couldn't boot with nvidia-384.

Comment: Oh maybe I should add that not nvidia-384 but nvidia-387 drivers are "installed" on my system or better the toolkit tried to install it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72353/discussion-between-karel-and-ock).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was solved by installing the network version which installs the nvidia driver 390.

In comparison the local version installs nvidia 387 which leads to problems on ubuntu 16.04.